# Excluding unknown categories when using tbl_continous in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

I would like to exclude categories with missing data(for multiple variables) when using `tbl_continuous` in `gtsummary` . In the code below, the missing data is included as "unknown" category and I would like to exclude this category.

Below is an example code;

```
library(gtsummary)

#introduce missing data
trial2<- trial %>% mutate(grade2= if_else(grade=="III", NA, grade))

tbl_continuous_ex2 <-
  tbl_continuous(
    data = trial2,
    variable = age,
    include = c(trt, grade2)
  )
```

Comment: You'll need to remove the rows with missing values before you pipe the data frame to `tbl_continuous()`